# In R Shiny, how to establish a reactivity chain for a series of linked matrix inputs?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

In the below "simplified" code, there are a series of 3 linked user input matrices. The user can opt to only modify Matrix 1 (giving a straight-line output, of value Y over slider input periods X). The user can opt to add a curve to the Matrix 1 "Y" value by inputting X and Y values into Matrix 2, with the matrix expanding vertically (adding rows) as the user adds inputs. The user can opt to add curve scenarios, in addition to the first curve generated in Matrix 2, by inputting X and Y values into Matrix 3 with this matrix expanding both horizontally and vertically. In plotting, Matrix 3 takes precedence over Matrix 2 and Matrix 2 takes precedence over Matrix 1. By "curve" I mean an interpolation/extrapolation function (UDF `interpol()`). Matrix 1 feeds into Matrix 2 which in turn feeds into Matrix 3. These downstream feeds seem to work fine except when going from Matrix 2 to Matrix 3 as described next.

When running the below, Matrix 1-only inputs work fine (as shown in the first image below). Matrix 3-only inputs work fine (as shown in the third image below). But Matrix 2 inputs don't work correctly: as you can see in the second image below, Matrix 2 inputs do not correctly downstream to Matrix 3.

What am I doing wrong here?

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

interpol <- function(a, b) { # [a] = modeled periods, [b] = matrix inputs
  c <- b
  c[,1][c[,1] > a] <- a
  d <- diff(c[,1, drop = FALSE])
  d[d <= 0] <- NA
  d <- c(1,d)
  c <- cbind(c,d)
  c <- na.omit(c)
  c <- c[,-c(3),drop=FALSE]
  e <- rep(NA, a)
  e[c[,1]] <- c[,2]
  e[seq_len(min(c[,1])-1)] <- e[min(c[,1])]
  if(max(c[,1]) < a){e[seq(max(c[,1]) + 1, a, 1)] <- 0}
  e <- approx(seq_along(e)[!is.na(e)], e[!is.na(e)], seq_along(e))$y # Interpolates
  return(e)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("slider"),
  h5(strong("Matrix 1:")), uiOutput("mat1"),
  h5(strong("Matrix 2:")), uiOutput("mat2"),
  h5(strong("Matrix 3:")), uiOutput("mat3"),
  plotOutput("plot")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output$slider <- renderUI({sliderInput('periods', 'Modeled periods (X):', min=1, max=10, value=10)})
  
  output$mat1 <- renderUI({
    matrixInput("matrix1", 
                value = matrix(c(5), 1, 1, dimnames = list("Base rate (Y)",NULL)),
                rows =  list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
                cols =  list(names = FALSE),
                class = "numeric")    
  })
  
  output$mat2 <- renderUI({
    matrixInput("matrix2",
                value = matrix(c(input$periods, input$matrix1[1,1]), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y"))),
                rows = list(extend = TRUE, names = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
                class = "numeric")
  })
  
  output$mat3 <- renderUI({
    matrixInput("matrix3",
                value = matrix(c(input$matrix2[,1], input$matrix2[,2]), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL, rep("Scenario 1", 2))),
                rows = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 1, names = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
                cols = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 2, names = TRUE, delete = TRUE, multiheader = TRUE),
                class = "numeric")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix2, { 
    if(any(rownames(input$matrix2) == "")){
      tmpMatrix <- input$matrix2
      rownames(tmpMatrix) <- paste("Row", seq_len(nrow(input$matrix2)))
      isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix2", value = tmpMatrix))
    }
    input$matrix2
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix3, {
    if(any(colnames(input$matrix3) == "")){
      tmpMatrix <- input$matrix3
      colnames(tmpMatrix) <- paste("Scenario",rep(1:ncol(tmpMatrix),each=2,length.out=ncol(tmpMatrix)))
      isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix3", value = tmpMatrix))
    }
    input$matrix3
  })
  
  plotData <- reactive({
    req(input$periods)
    tryCatch(
      lapply(seq_len(ncol(input$matrix3)/2), # column counter to set matrix index as it expands
              function(i){
                tibble(
                  Scenario = colnames(input$matrix3)[i*2-1],
                  X = seq_len(input$periods),
                  Y = interpol(input$periods,input$matrix3[,(i*2-1):(i*2), drop = FALSE])
                )
              }) %>% bind_rows(),
      error = function(e) NULL
    )
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(plotData())
    plotData() %>% ggplot() + 
      geom_line(aes(x = X, y = Y, colour = as.factor(Scenario))) +
      theme(legend.title=element_blank())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Alternative code, without using `renderUI` and instead relying on `observeEvent` with embedded `updateMatrixInput`:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput('periods', 'Modeled periods (X):', min=1, max=10, value=10),
  
  h5(strong("Matrix 1 is omitted for MWE")), 
  
  h5(strong("Matrix 2:")), 
  matrixInput("matrix2",
              value = matrix(c(10, 5), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y"))),
              rows = list(extend = TRUE, names = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
              class = "numeric"),
  
  h5(strong("Matrix 3:")), 
  matrixInput("matrix3",
              value = matrix(c(10,5), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, rep("Scenario 1", 2))),
              rows = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 1, names = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
              cols = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 2, names = TRUE, delete = TRUE, multiheader = TRUE),
              class = "numeric"),
  
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input$periods, {
    updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix2", 
      value = matrix(c(input$periods, 5), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y"))))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix2, { 
    if(any(rownames(input$matrix2) == "")){
      tmpMatrix <- input$matrix2
      rownames(tmpMatrix) <- paste("Row", seq_len(nrow(input$matrix2)))
      isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix2", value = tmpMatrix))
      isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix3", 
        value = tmpMatrix))
      }
    input$matrix2
    isolate(
      updateMatrixInput(
        session, 
        inputId = "matrix3", 
        value = matrix(
          c(input$matrix2[,1],input$matrix2[,2]), 
          ncol = 2, 
          dimnames = list(NULL, rep("Scenario 1", 2)))
      )
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix3, {
    if(any(colnames(input$matrix3) == "")){
      tmpMatrix <- input$matrix3
      colnames(tmpMatrix) <- paste("Scenario",rep(1:ncol(tmpMatrix),each=2,length.out=ncol(tmpMatrix)))
      isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix3", value = tmpMatrix))
    }
    input$matrix3
  })
  
  plotData <- reactive({
    req(input$periods)
    tryCatch(
      lapply(seq_len(ncol(input$matrix3)/2), # column counter to set matrix index as it expands
             function(i){
               tibble(
                 Scenario = colnames(input$matrix3)[i*2-1],
                 X = seq_len(input$periods),
                 Y = interpol(input$periods,input$matrix3[,(i*2-1):(i*2), drop = FALSE])
               )
             }) %>% bind_rows(),
      error = function(e) NULL
    )
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(plotData())
    plotData() %>% ggplot() + 
      geom_line(aes(x = X, y = Y, colour = as.factor(Scenario))) +
      theme(legend.title=element_blank())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `renderUI` call for `mat3` you are defining `nrow = 1`, which is taken into account every time the matrixInput is re-rendered.

You need to drop this argument to allow adding rows.

As you might know by now, in general I'd recommend dropping those `renderUI` calls.
I'd render the matrixInputs once on app start and modify them via `updateMatrixInput` - this is faster and keeps a clear separation between UI and server.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

interpol <- function(a, b) { # [a] = modeled periods, [b] = matrix inputs
  c <- b
  c[,1][c[,1] > a] <- a
  d <- diff(c[,1, drop = FALSE])
  d[d <= 0] <- NA
  d <- c(1,d)
  c <- cbind(c,d)
  c <- na.omit(c)
  c <- c[,-c(3),drop=FALSE]
  e <- rep(NA, a)
  e[c[,1]] <- c[,2]
  e[seq_len(min(c[,1])-1)] <- e[min(c[,1])]
  if(max(c[,1]) < a){e[seq(max(c[,1]) + 1, a, 1)] <- 0}
  e <- approx(seq_along(e)[!is.na(e)], e[!is.na(e)], seq_along(e))$y # Interpolates
  return(e)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("slider"),
  h5(strong("Matrix 1:")), uiOutput("mat1"),
  h5(strong("Matrix 2:")), uiOutput("mat2"),
  h5(strong("Matrix 3:")), uiOutput("mat3"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output$slider <- renderUI({sliderInput('periods', 'Modeled periods (X):', min=1, max=10, value=10)})
  
  output$mat1 <- renderUI({
    matrixInput("matrix1", 
                value = matrix(c(5), 1, 1, dimnames = list("Base rate (Y)",NULL)),
                rows =  list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
                cols =  list(names = FALSE),
                class = "numeric")    
  })
  
  output$mat2 <- renderUI({
    req(input$periods)
    req(input$matrix1)
    matrixInput("matrix2",
                value = matrix(c(input$periods, input$matrix1[1,1]), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y"))),
                rows = list(extend = TRUE, names = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
                class = "numeric")
  })
  
  output$mat3 <- renderUI({
    req(input$matrix2)
    matrixInput("matrix3",
                value = matrix(c(input$matrix2[,1], input$matrix2[,2]), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, rep("Scenario 1", 2))),
                rows = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 1, names = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
                cols = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 2, names = TRUE, delete = TRUE, multiheader = TRUE),
                class = "numeric")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix2, { 
    if(any(rownames(input$matrix2) == "")){
      tmpMatrix <- input$matrix2
      rownames(tmpMatrix) <- paste("Row", seq_len(nrow(input$matrix2)))
      isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix2", value = tmpMatrix))
    }
    input$matrix2
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix3, {
    if(any(colnames(input$matrix3) == "")){
      tmpMatrix <- input$matrix3
      colnames(tmpMatrix) <- paste("Scenario",rep(1:ncol(tmpMatrix),each=2,length.out=ncol(tmpMatrix)))
      isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix3", value = tmpMatrix))
    }
    input$matrix3
  })
  
  plotData <- reactive({
    req(input$periods)
    tryCatch(
      lapply(seq_len(ncol(input$matrix3)/2), # column counter to set matrix index as it expands
             function(i){
               tibble(
                 Scenario = colnames(input$matrix3)[i*2-1],
                 X = seq_len(input$periods),
                 Y = interpol(input$periods,input$matrix3[,(i*2-1):(i*2), drop = FALSE])
               )
             }) %>% bind_rows(),
      error = function(e) NULL
    )
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(plotData())
    plotData() %>% ggplot() + 
      geom_line(aes(x = X, y = Y, colour = as.factor(Scenario))) +
      theme(legend.title=element_blank())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: THANK YOU! But I should have been able to solve that... Your comment about eliminating renderUI calls: I tried that with this post because among many reasons it's much simpler for others to review the code. But I was unable to chain the matrices without renderUI:  with renderUI, matrix2 index = matrix1, matrix 3 index = matrix2, etc. But I'll try again and use updateMatrixInput, I've been wanting to drop renderUI. I know if I stay away from Shiny for a few months, when I see renderUI again it'll make no sense to me then.

Comment: OK I followed your suggestion and posted alternative code above without use of renderUI. Both look cumbersome to me: which do you think is better, with renderUI or without? I need to change direction now if I am abandoning the renderUI I've been hooked on.

Comment: I'd always prefer `update*` functions over `render*` functions, as they are modifying existing HTML instead of re-rendering it.