# In R Shiny, how to establish a downstream reactivity chain among linked input matrices using Observe Events?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

The following "Resolved code" resolves my original question (original question shown below this "Resolved code"). Basically I parse the upstream matrix values inside the `observeEvents` and then downstream them to the applicable matrix in the same `observeEvent`. I ask however: is this non-renderUI method better than the `renderUI` method shown in "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69718072/in-r-shiny-how-to-establish-a-reactivity-chain-for-a-series-of-linked-matrix-in"?

Resolved code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput('periods', 'Modeled periods (X):', min=1, max=10, value=10),
  
  h5(strong("Matrix 1 is omitted for MWE")), 
  
  h5(strong("Matrix 2:")), 
  matrixInput("matrix2",
              value = matrix(c(10, 5), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y"))),
              rows = list(extend = TRUE, names = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
              class = "numeric"),
  
  h5(strong("Matrix 3:")), 
  matrixInput("matrix3",
              value = matrix(c(10,5), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, rep("Scenario 1", 2))),
              rows = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 1, names = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
              cols = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 2, names = TRUE, delete = TRUE, multiheader = TRUE),
              class = "numeric"),
  
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input$periods, {
    updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix2", 
      value = matrix(c(input$periods, 5), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y"))))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix2, { 
    if(any(rownames(input$matrix2) == "")){
      tmpMatrix <- input$matrix2
      rownames(tmpMatrix) <- paste("Row", seq_len(nrow(input$matrix2)))
      isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix2", value = tmpMatrix))
      isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix3", 
        value = tmpMatrix))
      }
    input$matrix2
    isolate(
      updateMatrixInput(
        session, 
        inputId = "matrix3", 
        value = matrix(
          c(input$matrix2[,1],input$matrix2[,2]), 
          ncol = 2, 
          dimnames = list(NULL, rep("Scenario 1", 2)))
      )
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix3, {
    if(any(colnames(input$matrix3) == "")){
      tmpMatrix <- input$matrix3
      colnames(tmpMatrix) <- paste("Scenario",rep(1:ncol(tmpMatrix),each=2,length.out=ncol(tmpMatrix)))
      isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix3", value = tmpMatrix))
    }
    
    input$matrix3
  })
  
  plotData <- reactive({
    req(input$periods)
    tryCatch(
      lapply(seq_len(ncol(input$matrix3)/2), # column counter to set matrix index as it expands
             function(i){
               tibble(
                 Scenario = colnames(input$matrix3)[i*2-1],
                 X = seq_len(input$periods),
                 Y = interpol(input$periods,input$matrix3[,(i*2-1):(i*2), drop = FALSE])
               )
             }) %>% bind_rows(),
      error = function(e) NULL
    )
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(plotData())
    plotData() %>% ggplot() + 
      geom_line(aes(x = X, y = Y, colour = as.factor(Scenario))) +
      theme(legend.title=element_blank())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is a follow-on to my earlier post today "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69718072/in-r-shiny-how-to-establish-a-reactivity-chain-for-a-series-of-linked-matrix-in". In the code in that post, I used `renderUI` for the matrices and their links and it works well (as corrected by ismirsehregal). I'm trying to move away from `renderUI` (for sake of simplicity) and use `updateMatrixInput` inside `observeEvent` in order to maintain a reactivity chain without `renderUI`.

The below without-renderUI code ALMOST works like the `renderUI` version posted earlier, except I can't get the slider input `input$periods` to reactively downstream to the matrices, as shown in the image below. Also, I lost the automatic generation of sequential column headers for Matrix 3 in the below code, as shown in the image.

Basically, I don't know how to parse or subset inputs into `updateMatrixInput`; as the below code is drafted, it takes the entire set of matrix values that is being downstreamed from, thus giving rise to my issue. If I could tell it which matrix rows/columns to take in for updating, then it would work.

Maybe the answer in this case is sticking with `renderUI` if parsing/subsetting is not possible?

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

interpol <- function(a, b) { # [a] = modeled periods, [b] = matrix inputs
  c <- b
  c[,1][c[,1] > a] <- a
  d <- diff(c[,1, drop = FALSE])
  d[d <= 0] <- NA
  d <- c(1,d)
  c <- cbind(c,d)
  c <- na.omit(c)
  c <- c[,-c(3),drop=FALSE]
  e <- rep(NA, a)
  e[c[,1]] <- c[,2]
  e[seq_len(min(c[,1])-1)] <- e[min(c[,1])]
  if(max(c[,1]) < a){e[seq(max(c[,1]) + 1, a, 1)] <- 0}
  e <- approx(seq_along(e)[!is.na(e)], e[!is.na(e)], seq_along(e))$y # Interpolates
  return(e)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput('periods', 'Modeled periods (X):', min=1, max=10, value=10),
  
  h5(strong("Matrix 1 is omitted for MWE")), 
  
  h5(strong("Matrix 2:")), 
  matrixInput("matrix2",
              value = matrix(c(10, 5), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y"))),
              rows = list(extend = TRUE, names = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
              class = "numeric"),
  
  h5(strong("Matrix 3:")), 
  matrixInput("matrix3",
              value = matrix(c(10, 5), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, rep("Scenario 1", 2))),
              rows = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 1, names = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
              cols = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 2, names = TRUE, delete = TRUE, multiheader = TRUE),
              class = "numeric"),
  
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix2, { 
    if(any(rownames(input$matrix2) == "")){
      tmpMatrix <- input$matrix2
      rownames(tmpMatrix) <- paste("Row", seq_len(nrow(input$matrix2)))
      isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix2", value = tmpMatrix))
      isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix3", value = tmpMatrix))
    }
    input$matrix2
    isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix3", value = input$matrix2))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix3, {
    if(any(colnames(input$matrix3) == "")){
      tmpMatrix <- input$matrix3
      colnames(tmpMatrix) <- paste("Scenario",rep(1:ncol(tmpMatrix),each=2,length.out=ncol(tmpMatrix)))
      isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix3", value = tmpMatrix))
    }
    
    input$matrix3
  })
  
  plotData <- reactive({
    req(input$periods)
    tryCatch(
      lapply(seq_len(ncol(input$matrix3)/2), # column counter to set matrix index as it expands
             function(i){
               tibble(
                 Scenario = colnames(input$matrix3)[i*2-1],
                 X = seq_len(input$periods),
                 Y = interpol(input$periods,input$matrix3[,(i*2-1):(i*2), drop = FALSE])
               )
             }) %>% bind_rows(),
      error = function(e) NULL
    )
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(plotData())
    plotData() %>% ggplot() + 
      geom_line(aes(x = X, y = Y, colour = as.factor(Scenario))) +
      theme(legend.title=element_blank())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Your only dependency on `input$periods` is in your `output$plot`.  That's why your observe events don't react to changes to `input$periods`.  I think your fundamental problem is that your code (here and in your other related posts) conflates _input_, _manipulation_ and _presentation_.  This is never a good idea.  I would make your matrices `reactive`s.  You then trigger updates to your inputs in response to changes to your matrix `reactive`s.  But recursion will be an issue, since you also want to trigger changes to your `reactive`s in response to changes to your `input`.  But it can be done.

Comment: In `observeEvent(input$matrix2, {...})` you have `isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix3", value = input$matrix2))`.  Perhaps the ID should be `matrix2`.

Comment: Hi YBS, that referenced line of code actually works to downstream matrix2 values to matrix3. I tried your change as well as commenting-out that line and matrix value downstreaming no longer works. I'm trying to figure out how to decompose the "upstream" matrix values so only the required upstream matrix values are downstreamed. Then I can start downstreaming input$periods, creating the desired dependencies. I don't know if this will be easier to follow than using renderUI which does work.

Comment: Post above revised code that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Resolved code" above posted as an edit to the original question resolves this issue (original question shown below the "Resolved code"). Basically the upstream matrix values are parsed inside an `observeEvent` and are then downstreamed to the applicable matrix in the same `observeEvent`. Regarding the question raised: "*is this non-`renderUI` method better than the `renderUI` method shown in...?*" My answer is absolutely yes - removing the `renderUI` leaves you with much cleaner, easier to follow code. I just had to get more comfortable with embedding matrix parsing code inside an `observeEvent`. I also understand the code will run quicker without `renderUI` since objects are only edited and not completely re-rendered as occurs with `renderUI`.